# How to get struct field from refect.Value

Tags: reflection, go

Given

```
type Runnable interface {
     Run()
}

type T struct {
    Z struct {
        A int
    }
}

func (t T) Run() {
    t.Z.A = 1
}

func main() {
    t := reflect.TypeOf( T{} )

    var v reflect.Value
    v = reflect.New(t).Elem()

    runnable := v.Interface().(Runnable)
    runnable.Run()
```

Is there a way, at the end, to retrive Z and its field values as set by the `Run()` method?

I am implementing an API command pattern, so `T` could be `RegisterCommand`, `LoginCommand`, `LogoutCommand` etc. Z is the 'output doc' - a JSON doc returned by the API command - which I want to specify declaratively and have written to the network after the command is run.

Comment: Your problem is that `Run()` takes a value receiver. This means that the value of `t` is copied, and the modification `t.Z.A = 1` only applies to the copy. Thus, the object you call it on won't be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Thank you to synful for the 'pointer' :-)

```
    z := v.Elem().FieldByName("Z").Interface()
```